# Get length of record field of type array

Tags: delphi

I'm writing a wrapper for communication with an external binary API. The API uses PDUs (packed binary records) for communication. Strings are arrays of AnsiChar and are zero-terminated:

```
type 
  TSomePDU = packed record
    //...
    StringField: array[0..XYZ] of AnsiChar;
    //...
  end;
  PSomePDU = ^TSomePDU;
```

I want to write a FillPDUString procedure that would accept a String and fill the char array, but I want to avoid keeping track of MaxLength wherever the procedure is used, so I need somehow to get the declared array size given a pointer to the field:

```
function GetMaxSize(const Field: array of AnsiChar): Integer;
begin
  // ???
end;

//...
GetMaxSize(ARecord.StringField);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you can use Delphi's [Length](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Length) function

Here's how to get the length:

```
function GetMaxSize(const Value: PSomePDU): Integer; 
begin
  Result := Length(Value.StringField);
end;
```

Comment: Just a minor correction, the signature should be `function GetMaxSize(const Field: array of AnsiChar)` and the body `Result=Length(Field);`, because the point was to get the max length of any arbitrary field given the pointer to the *field*, hence the `const Field: array of AnsiChar`.

Comment: @BorisB. it depends on how you look at it, but I prefer passing the entire record so I don't have to do GetMaxSize( APDURecord.StringField ) for each call...

Comment: Yes, but there can be many different PDUs, and one PDU can have many different string fields in it, writing it your way would limit you to one particular field of one particular record. Besides, now I know that the simple `Length` is the solution I don't need the func anyway, since it's only used for a `FillPDUString` func, which checks for overflow before filling.

Answer (score 6):

To obtain the number of elements that an array contains, use `Length`.

```
ElementCount := Length(ARecord.StringField);
```

Use `low` and `high` to obtain the bounds of any Delphi array.

```
MinIndex := low(ARecord.StringField);
MaxIndex := high(ARecord.StringField);
```

Using the latter approach, with `low` and `high`, allows you to avoid assuming that an array is 0-based.

Comment: +1 for the Low and High, usually people assume arrays are zero based, whenever I have the chance, I make them non-zero based just so it makes life a bit spicier ^_^

Comment: Thank you very much, Dorin was a just minute faster with the same answer, and I had to pick one.

Comment: Nice to see you rewarding speed rather than quality! ;-) Seriously though, accept the best answer. I make no comment as to which of these two it is, but you should always pick the best answer, no matter when it arrives. And I would say the same, and have done many times, even when my answer was fast, but a later answer was better.

Comment: `Length(a) = High(a) - Low(a) + 1` (My 2 cents)

Comment: @BorisB. David is right, speed is not the essence, but the quality of the answer.