# How does System.Length() work for static arrays in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi

A few years ago I [posted a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887307/get-length-of-record-field-of-type-array) on how to get the an array's declared length at runtime, if that array is in a packed record. And the answer was simple, use the `Length()` function, just as with other arrays. I'm now seeing what was the source of my confusion at the time. Here is the record from the original question:

```
type 
  TSomePDU = packed record
    //...
    StringField: array[0..XYZ] of AnsiChar;
    //...
  end;
  PSomePDU = ^TSomePDU;
```

A static array is just a continuous memory block. For every allocated memory block the memory manager keeps track of the pointer and the block's size. Since we know the block's size then we can get the array's declared length by dividing the size of the memory block with the size of the array's element type. Maybe that's not how `Length()` works, but I see no reason why it shouldn't.

My problem is that the array in question is in a *packed record*. A packed record is treated as a memory chunk which is allocated and deallocated as a whole. So there should be no separate allocation of the static array when it is in a packed record, the array is there just to provide typed access to a subset of bytes in that record, so that compile-time checks could take place. I also know that there are no hidden bytes in front of the static array that hold the array's length.

So then how does the `Length()` function work for such an array?

Comment: It looks like the length is substituted with the function call at compile time. There doesn't seem to be any calculation, function call etc. if you look at the assembly view.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: But if a pass a pointer to that array to some function (GetMaxSize in my original question linked), then that function _can_ call `Length()`. So it can't be replaced at compile time.

Comment: Check out System._DynArrayLength

Comment: @Boris - In the case of the question you linked, it's determined at the call site, then passed to the function. An open array parameter has both the pointer to the first array element and an integer length.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: It's fields are aligned at the byte boundary, that's why it's called 'packed'. One field immediately follows the other in terms of memory layout.

Comment: Yes, I know about `$A-`. You didn't explain why `$A+` record allocated not as whole memory block.

Comment: Why are you packing? Mis-aligning data hurts perf.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Because the record is a PDU, it gets marshaled to an external C API which expects a certain memory layout. And since there were a lot of different PDUs in the API was writing a function for filling arrays of AnsiChar from a String, and I needed length for bounds checks. More info is in the linked question.

Comment: It's a shame that the records are packed though. That means that they may well be mis-aligned. Usually you can layout the record so there is no padding and have alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Length()` function is an [intrinsic function](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines).

When you apply it to a [static array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Static_Arrays), the compiler knows the result at compile time. And so no function call is made and the compiler emits code with the length value stored as a constant in the executable.

This is true irrespective of where the static array is declared. It just does not matter whether it is a global, a local, in an aligned record or a packed record, or in a class.

Comment: Could you please just clarify how does it work if I pass an array's pointer to a function which then calls `Length()` on it. How does that compile-time determined info _survive_ passing as a pointer?

Comment: @BorisB. Well, that's a different question. And what I believe you really mean is that you pass an *open array* rather than a pointer. From a pointer you cannot recover length. An open array is implemented by passing two things: the index of the last item, and a pointer to the first element. In the function that receives the open array, the `Length()` function is implemented by adding 1 to the index of the last item.

Comment: But if I do, for example, `Pointer p =  MyStaticArray; MyOpenArray = p` then that length info should essentially be lost? Or is that kind of a conversion prohibited? I don't have Delphi ATM so I cannot try it.

Comment: @BorisB. That code does not compile. You cannot assign to open arrays. Then can only be used as parameters. And so the information is not lost. If you attempt to call `Length()` on a pointer, then you will find that it does not compile because a pointer is not an array.

Comment: @BorisB.: it is quite simple. The length of a static array is known at compile time, so the compiler simply compiles a constant when you "call" Length. The length of a dynamic array is stored with the data, it a field at a negative offset from the start of the data. The length (or actually the High value) of an open array, which can only be a parameter, is passed to the function that declares the open array, along with the pointer to the data. So as parameter, it is actually a twofold parameter. The compiler inserts code that passes the correct values for each kind of array.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I agree that it's simple, but from the outside it's not obvious how it works (it could even be called _magic_). Especially given that docs for System.Length specifically state "string or dynamic array", no static arrays are mentioned.

Comment: @BorisB, that's because you are supposed to use `Low(A)..High(A)` for regular arrays and open arrays. `0..Length(A)-1` is a bonus.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: I don't think that's the reason. If Length works for static arrays then the docs should reflect that.

Comment: @BorisB, [they](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Structured_Types#Static_Arrays) [do](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Open_Array_Parameters).

Comment: @FreeConsulting, No they [don't](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Length). Your docs links are for static arrays and open arrays, I'm talking about docs for the `System.Length()` where it states `function Length(S: <string or dynamic array>): Integer;`.

Comment: @Free The documentation could be clearer here to be fair. Yes the description talks generally of array valued expressions. But for such a foundational function I think it would better be more explicit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, this applies for the whole Delphi intrinsics universe, unfortunately. At least it has been documented elsewhere (bless the full-text search!).

Comment: @Free Yes, I found the docs in the section on static arrays, as linked from my answer.